# Convert simple string to List<int>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple response by REST API with tis string:

```
var convertDataToJson = jsonDecode(response.body);

String listItem = convertDataToJson[0]['note']; //"[1,4,7]";
```

I want to convert **listItem** to list of int

```
listItem = [1,4,7]
```

Comment: invoke `jsonDecode` on your String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final data = '[1,4,7]';
  final intList = jsonDecode(data);
  print(intList[1]); // 4
}
```